# Executing queries with EntityManager in Spring+Hibernate project

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a Spring + Hibernate project with configured DataSource:

```
@Configuration
@Component
  public class DataSourceConfig {

  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
      return DataSourceBuilder
          .create()
          .url("jdbc:firebirdsql://**********:3050/mydb?charSet=utf8")
          .username("*****")
          .password("*****")
          .driverClassName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver")
          .build();
  }
}
```

EntityManagerFactoriesConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class EntityManagerFactoriesConfig {
  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[]{"ekoncept"});           
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(
            new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    return emf;
  }
}
```

TransactionManagerConfig:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagersConfig {
  @Autowired
  EntityManagerFactory emf;
  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager tm =
            new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    tm.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tm;
  }
}
```

and that's all, no db config in application.properties.

Now I want to access EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory to execute SQL. I know that I should use @Query annotation with Spring, but in this one case I need to execute a simple SQL. I was trying to do it in many ways and finally in all cases I got EntityManager==null. How to get access to Entity manager or EntityManagerFactory??

Comment: Why that contraption? Just use a `JdbcTemplate` to execute the query. Or if you really want to use the `SessionFactory` use that, but please don't use this contraption. Also judging from the fact you use `@ConfigurationProperties` you are using Spring Boot, however this code shows that you are trying very hard not to use spring Boot.

Comment: @Olek You included a username and password in your post. (@Leviand fixed that for you, but the data is still visible in the edit history.) You should consider this username and password combination compromised and insecure. If you care at all about the resources secured by this username and password, you should at least change the password.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SpringBoot. In rest of code I use Hibernate, I have entities and daos in project. So I'm using Spring, but in one method I need to generate ID from sequence manually. Maybe there is any mechanism to do it manually in Hibernate?? If not I want to use EntityManager because I know how to use it. One missing thing is hot to get EntityManager when I'm using Spring??

Comment: @M.Deinum I've updated my question, maybe now it will more clear what I'm going to do... I was looking at JdbcTemplate, but I don't want to use advenced mechanism like that (I have already Hibernate - that's enough). I need only access to working EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory and I will do rest.

Comment: Just obtain the entity manager lik you regularly would do. Also if you are Spring Boot you don't need the configuration you have now, Spring Boot does all of that already.

Comment: @M.Deinum Problem is that I have never used EntityManager directly in my project. I use Query annotation and DAO for queries and it works fine. But I have one situation where I need access EntityManager directly. I think if I have configured DB access in DataSource I should could do it. How??

Comment: As stated you are trying very hard NOT to use spring boot. Spring Boot already configures all of that for you (`DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory` and `JpaTransactionManager`). So you don't need that configuration. If you want the entitymanager just do that as ou normally would in a plain JPA application.